# Continuous deployment with docker

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I m actually working with a stack that allows me to make some automation in my integration / deployment system.

Actually I work like following :

- I push my code to a github repository
- Jenkins sniffs the repo and build the soft, launch unit testing
- If unit testing (or other kind of tests, anyway), it notifies Rundeck to deploy to my servers (3 in my case) by connecting into SSH and telling : "hey guy, you have to pull from github, new soft version is available", then it restarts the the concerned service and my soft is now up to date

Okay, tell me if I m wrong, but it seems to be a good solution right ?

Then, I wanted to containerize my applications and now, I got some headaches.

**First solution**

In fact, I was wondering about something like :

- Push to github
- Jenkins tests, builds the docker image
- Rundeck push to docker hub and tells the 3 servers to pull back the new image from the hub and run it through SSH

Problem : it will run in another container (multiple docker run of the same image, but with different versions :( )

**Second solution**

The second solution was to :

- Push to github
- Jenkins tests and tells rundeck that the test successes, without create a "real build" (only one for testing)
- Rundeck connects to the running *container* through ssh and ask to pull the modifications, then it restarts the docker container

Problem : I am forced to use ssh in all my containers

I dont know how to bypass my problems, and what is the best solution...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with solution 1.

1.Build production version with jenkins

2.Push it (via jenkins) to your private docker registry

3.Tell Rundeck/Ansible/Chef/Puppet ask 3 servers to pull latest image and restart container.

However, it's highly recommended to have some strategy, which considers **blue-green** principle and rollbacks if something is crashed.